# How to generate DFP native ad unit id android

Tags: android, google-dfp

I want to generate DFP native ad unit id for my android application, I searched on Google but did not find any good tutorial which gives the exact idea of generating this id.

Please post here if anyone have any idea.

Thanks a lot in advanced !!!

Answer (score 0):

In your DFP account, you can find this under Inventory > Ad units.

Once you have created and saved your ad unit, go back to edit it. A button called Generate tags will be available. Click on it, and you will be able to retrieve the Ad unit ID for your mobile app.

based on 
[How to use your DFP account to display ads in your mobile app](http://blog.goodbarber.com/How-to-use-your-DFP-account-to-display-ads-in-your-mobile-app_a342.html)